Flutter json login issue
I made login system in flutter using locally stored json file when a user registers it adds their information in json file and when they login it checks the json it works perfectly fine in visual studio but after i build an exe and tried it doesn't work it's says email or password is incorrect
here is the login function
i have added the json path into pubspec.yaml file
Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // Prevent user from dismissing the dialog
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    Navigator.pop(context);

    // Read user data from JSON
    final users = await readData();

    // Find user by email and password
    final matchingUser = users.firstWhere(
        (user) => user['email'] == email && user['password'] == password,
        orElse: () => null);

    // Check for Natural department
    final isNatural =
        matchingUser != null && matchingUser['department'] == 'Natural';

    if (matchingUser != null) {
      if (isNatural) {
        Get.to(() => const NaturalPage());
      } else {
        Get.to(() => const SocialPage());
      }
      print('Login successful!');
    } else {
      setState(() {});
      emailError = 'Email or password is incorrect';
      passwordError = 'Email or password is incorrect';
      print('Login failed!');
    }
  }

i didn't try anything because i don't know what to do
